# ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument (Incorrect array shape)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, timeit

I've looked at the other threads about this error, but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to update [this](https://github.com/cseager/timeit_plot/blob/master/timeit_plot.py) repository to python 3, but I keep getting this error.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    266         # float)` and `np.array(...).astype(float)` all convert "0.5" to 0.5.
    267         # Test dimensionality to reject single floats.
--> 268         raise ValueError(f"Invalid RGBA argument: {orig_c!r}")
    269     # Return a tuple to prevent the cached value from being modified.
    270     c = tuple(c.astype(float))

ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: [(array([0.5, 0. , 1. , 1. ]),), (array([0.50392157, 0.99998103, 0.70492555, 1.        ]),), (array([1.0000000e+00, 1.2246468e-16, 6.1232340e-17, 1.0000000e+00]),)]
```

Here is the code I modified.

```
def timeit_plot2D(data, xlabel='xlabel', title='title', **kwargs):
    """Plots the results from a defaultdict returned by timeit_compare.
    
    Each function will be plotted as a different series. 
    
    timeit_compare may test many conditions, and the order of the conditions
    in the results data can be understood from the string substitutions 
    noted in the keys of the defaultdict. By default series=0 means
    that the first series is plotted, but this can be changed to plot 
    any of the testing conditions available. 
    """
    series = kwargs.get('series', 0)
    style = kwargs.get('style', 'line')
    size = kwargs.get('size', 500)
    ylabel = kwargs.get('ylabel', 'time')
    cmap = kwargs.get('cmap', 'rainbow')
    lloc = kwargs.get('lloc', 2)
    dataT = {}
    # set color scheme
    c = iter(plt.get_cmap(cmap)(np.linspace(0, 1, len(data))))
    # transpose the data from [x, y, z]... into ([x...], [y...], [z...])
    for k, v in data.items():
        dataT[k] = list(zip(*v))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for k, v in dataT.items():
        if style == 'scatter':
            ax.scatter(v[series], v[-1], s=size, c=next(c), alpha=.75)
        elif style == 'bubble':
            x, y, z = v[series[0]], v[series[1]], v[-1]
            ax.scatter(x, y, s=[size*i for i in z], c=next(c), alpha=.5)
        else: 
            ax.plot(v[series], v[-1], c=list(zip(c)), lw=2)
    # TODO: BUG: no way to set other parameters manually (README fig2)
    ax.legend([substitute_titles(k,series) for k in dataT.keys()], loc=lloc)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.grid(True)
    return fig
```

I believe the issue to be on this line.

```
c = iter(plt.get_cmap(cmap)(np.linspace(0, 1, len(data))))
```

But, I've been having trouble converting it to something that makes sense.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the full error? I'm quite sure that's not the full error because it doesn't tell in which line of your code the error occured (only the line for the matplotlib module). From the looks of it it seems like you're passing a list of numpy arrays at some point, instead of a single colormap, so that may be the cause. If we knew exactly where it fails in your script it would be helpful. If I were to guess it's probably this line ```ax.plot(v[series], v[-1], c=list(zip(c)), lw=2)```

Comment: ```print(list(zip(c)))``` produces a list like the one referenced in the error: ```[(array([0.5, 0. , 1. , 1. ]),), (array([0.50392157, 0.99998103, 0.70492555, 1.        ]),), (array([1.0000000e+00, 1.2246468e-16, 6.1232340e-17, 1.0000000e+00]),)]
```

Comment: Just as a final comment: I think your issue will resolve if you use ```list(c)``` instead of ```list(zip(c))``` but I can't be sure because you didn't add the full code (or really the data you use to generate the plots) so I can't replicate it and check if it works before posting it as an answer.

Comment: I tried a few things, but abandoned the tool. I'm going to close this question as I'm not going to try and solve it. Thanks for the input.